# Constructing a countable number of independent Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a probability triple, $([0,1], \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Borel $\sigma$ algebra on $[0,1]$, how can we construct a countable number of independent Bernoulli random variables on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Flip a coin countably many times?

Comment: That depends on the "sample probability space". Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Hint: One way is to note that any $\omega \in [0,1]$ has it's binary expansion ( $\omega = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\omega_n}{2^n}$ where $\omega_n \in \{0,1\}$ (if $\omega$ has two expansions, choose one such that $\omega_k=0$ for every $k \ge N$)).Then family $\{X_n\}$ of random variables such that $X_n(\omega) = \omega_n$ should do the trick. (This is exactly what @saulspatz mentioned). With some work you can create countably many $\mathcal Unif(0,1)$ independent random variables (and from there countably many i.i.d random variables with given distribution $\mu$)

Comment: My intuition says $\{X_n\}$ should be independent, but is there any way to see this more in connection to the definition of independent random variables?